# Comparison between dates returning odd results

Tags: java, hibernate, date

I calculated one date with `Calendar` class and then compared it to two dates which I got from a query executed with Hibernate. When I compare the dates I am getting "not equal" when I compare `endDate` with `thisIter`.

I tried printing some debug statements. If I print as a `Date` I see a slight difference in the printed text in line 1. However, if I format it with SDF and print, they look exactly same in the printed text in line 2.

What is the difference in the dates and why is it not showing up in SDF formated value.

This is the code I am using to print the debug:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
System.out.println(thisIter + ": " + new Date(r.getFromDate().getTime()) + "(" +  new Date(thisIter.getTime()) + ")" +  new Date(r.getToDate().getTime()));
System.out.println(thisIter + ": " + sdft.format(r.getFromDate().getTime()) + "(" +  sdft.format(thisIter.getTime()) + ")" +  sdft.format(r.getToDate().getTime()));
```

This is the output:

```
Wed Oct 07 12:00:00 IST 2015: Sat Oct 03 00:00:00 IST 2015(Wed Oct 07 12:00:00 IST 2015)Wed Oct 07 00:00:00 IST 2015
Wed Oct 07 12:00:00 IST 2015: 03102015120000(07102015120000)07102015120000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

- `HH` Hour in day (0-23)
- `hh` Hour in am/pm (1-12)

Example:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
```

So you can see you have 12 on one side, and 00 on the other.

Comment: I have written a truncate function which is supposed to remove the time component. Only, it leaves the date at 12 noon instead of midnight!! That's because I used c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0); instead of c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);